# Well-definedness of assinging a value to a point of a manifold with respect to parallelism

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

By definition as in DoCarmo’s Riemannian Geometry book, in a smooth manifold $M$ a vector field $V$ along a smooth curve $c:(a,b)\rightarrow M$ is a mapping $t\mapsto V(t)\in T_{c(t)}M$ such that $t\mapsto V(t)f$ is a smooth map for all smooth maps $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$.

Suppose that $c_1,c_2$ are two smooth curves in $M$ such that $c_1(t_0)=c_2(t_0)$, and $c_1(t_1)=c_2(t_1)$ where $t_0$ and $t_1$ are two distinct points in the (same) domain of $c_1,c_2$. Suppose that $V_0\in T_{c_1(t_0)}M$. There exists a unique parallel vector field $V_1$ along $c_1$ such that $V_1(t_0)=V_0$, and similarly a unique $V_2$ along $c_2$ such that $V_2(t_0)=V_0$. Does it follow that $V_1(t_1)=V_2(t_1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily, unless the space is *flat*. This is actually a definition; a space is flat if and only if the property you ask about holds. The Euclidean space is flat.

These things are the starting point of the concept of *curvature*.

The following picture is taken from Wikipedia and it shows how the choice of a path can produce different parallel trasported vectors, in the case of the sphere.

[image: Wikipedia - Parallel transport and curvature]

Comment: Thanks for this intuitive illustration